How to edit Android SDK sources?
I need to change the code in SDK 34 to get a good result for my program, but I can't do it because the sources are read-only. I tried decompiler, but it doesn't recompile the changed code.
For example, I need to change the maximum overhead of encryption algorithms, which are bound to constants defined by IANA

And a lot of things need to be changed in the source code of SDK 34. Maybe there is some alternative to SDK 34 with the ability to change the code for myself?

What do you mean you need to change the code in SDK 34? Please clarify your question and add more details.

Why do you "need" to change the source code? If you actually do, you're probably looking at building the entire platform from source. Godspeed.
